# Unitary representations of a non-compact Lie group $G$

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $G$ is a simply-connected, non-compact complex Lie group, and if $(\mathcal{H}, \pi)$ is a unitary representation of $G$ on Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, does it follow that $\pi$ is reducible, i.e it can be written as a direct sum of infinite-dimensional irreducible representations?

In the post [Infinite-dimensional Unitary representions that are not completely reducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533598/infinite-dimensional-unitary-representions-that-are-not-completely-reducible), my question seems to have been already addressed as follows:

> Non-compact semisimple Lie groups in general have many interesting
> irreducible infinite-dimensional representations, some but not all of
> which are unitarizable. It's still true that unitary representations
> are completely reducible (and the proof is the same), but often there
> are no nontrivial finite-dimensional ones: for example, if $G$ is a
> noncompact simple Lie group such as $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$, it can't
> embed into any unitary group $U(n)$ (all of which are compact).